# How to add subfolder to requests urls in Swagger in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API with swagger.

I have the frontend of my application hosted on the root domain and the API hosted in the `api` folder.

The Swagger UI opens on `https:[domain]/api/swagger/index.html` but all endpoints in swagger are still on the `root` directory `https:[domain]`:

[image]

This is causing a http 500 error.

I've tried adding `api` to the `Route` in all controller like:

```
namespace ApiProject.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CompaniesController : ControllerBase
    {
        .....

    }
}
```

But that is adding additional `api` in all endpoints.
for example : `https://[domain]/api/api/companies/getall`

How can I add the `api` subfolder to all Swagger requests without it effecting the endpoints urls?

Comment: You should fix your endpoint mappings. To get better assistance you should show more relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your api has a route with something like this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class YourController : ControllerBase
{
  //Your content
}
```

Otherwise, please edit your question with more details

See more details inside the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio-code) search for the  Routing and URL paths section

Comment: adding `api` in the route of the controller is adding additional `api` folder to the endpoint domain e.g. `https://[domain]/api/api/countries/getall` instead of `https://[domain]/api/countries/getall`

Comment: just remove the api part in the Route, just use `[Route("[controller]")]`

Comment: I've done that obviously but I'm hosting my app on `http://[domain]/api` so how can add this `/api` to swagger endpoint urls without altering the routes of the controller because I don't want to change the endpoints urls